# Delete all records unless 1 or more sub record meet a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-delete

If I have a table "Cars" with a 1-to-many joined table "Passengers" how can I delete all cars that don't have one or more passengers named "Jim"?

If it makes it simpler, their is a static amount of other passenger names. Let's say only "Peggy", "Maggy", and "Sue". Doesn't sound like it would be that hard but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE c FROM Cars c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Passengers p
    WHERE p.Name = 'Jim'
      AND p.CarID = c.ID
)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4705b/5/0)

Presumed that `CarID` is the foreign-key and `ID` is the primary key in Cars.

Comment: @user2535309 if you are happy with this answer then you should accept it be clicking the faded tick to the left.

Comment: I plan to once I'm allowed to. Still says I have to wait some time.